# How can I write a batch file using jq to find json files with certain attribute and copy the to new location

Tags: json, batch-file, cmd, jq

I have 100,000's of lined json files that I need to split out based on whether or not, they contain a certain value for an attribute and then I need to convert them into valid json that can be read in by another platform.

I'm using a batch file to do this and I've managed to convert them into valid json using the following:

```
for /r %%f in (*.json*) do jq -s -c "." "%%f" >> "C:\Users\me\my-folder\%%~nxf.json"
```

I just can't figure out how to only copy the files that contain a certain value. So logic should be:

```
Look at all the files in the folders and sub solders
  If the file contains an attribute "event" with a value of "abcd123"
  then: convert the file into valid json and persist it with the same filename over to location "C:\Users\me\my-folder\"
  else: ignore it
```

**Example of files it should select:**

```
{"name":"bob","event":"abcd123"}
```

and

```
{"name":"ann","event":"abcd123"},{"name":"bob","event":"8745LLL"}
```

**Example of files it should NOT select:**

```
{"name":"ann","event":"778PPP"}
```

and

```
{"name":"ann","event":"778PPP"},{"name":"bob","event":"8745LLL"}
```

Would love help to figure out the filtering part.

Comment: The last example is neither valid JSON nor a stream of valid JSON entities. Please clarify whether you intended this, and if so, whether this non-JSON-stream type of file can be assumed to be comma-separated JSON

Comment: Thanks for getting back. The last examples with two json objects in the are not valid. This is true. It's an example of what the files actually look like though (of which I have no control). Yes you can assume it to be comma-seperated json.

Comment: Mods, please can we reopen this question. I'm not entirely clear on why it was closed in the first place?

Comment: @inian - Could you please consider voting to re-open this question, which seems to have been closed because of one of the proposed answers.

Comment: @oguzismail - Could you please consider voting to re-open this question, which seems to have been closed because of one of the proposed answers.

Comment: It's been reopened now.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are probably more file names than will fit on the command line, this response will assume a shell loop through the file names will be necessary, as the question itself envisions. Since I'm currently working with a bash shell, I'll present a bash solution, which hopefully can readily be translated to other shells.

The complication in the question is that the input file might contain one or more valid JSON values, or one or more comma-separated JSON values.

The key to a simple solution using jq is jq's -e command-line option, since this sets the return code to 0 if and only if
(a) the program ran normally; and (b) the last result was a truthy value.

For clarity, let's encapsulate the relevant selection criterion in two bash functions:

```
# If the input is a valid stream of JSON objects
function try {
  jq -e -n 'any( inputs | objects; select( .event == "abcd123") | true)' 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
}


# If the input is a valid JSON array whose elements are to be checked
function try_array {
  jq -e 'any( .[] | objects; select( .event == "abcd123") | true)' 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
}
```

Now a comprehensive solution can be constructed along the following lines:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '*.json' | while read -r f
do
  < "$f" try
  if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
      echo copy $f
  elif [ $? = 5 ] ; then
      (echo '['; cat "$f"; echo ']') | try_array
      if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
      echo copy $f
      fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: Amazing, will give this a go at the weekend and come back to you! Many thanks! :)

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered using [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr)?

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /SRM "\"event\":\"abcd123\"" "C:\Users\me\my-folder\*.json"
```

Please open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr /?`, press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, and read its usage information. *(You may want to consider the `/I` option too, for instance)*.

You could then use that within another for loop to propagate those files into a variable for your copy command.

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example:

```
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /SRM "\"event\":\"abcd123\"" "C:\Users\me\my-folder\*.json"'
) Do @Copy /Y "%%G" "S:\omewhere Else"
```

[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) example:

```
For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /SRM "\"event\":\"abcd123\"" "C:\Users\me\my-folder\*.json"') Do @Copy /Y "%G" "S:\omewhere Else"
```

Comment: Despite this not using `jq`, it works regardless of whether your file is a valid JSON, or not. _I have just tested it and it works exactly as intended_. Whomever downvoted the solution, should be aware that the [[tag:batch-file]], [[tag:cmd]], and [[tag:json]] tags are all relevant to this answer, and therefore future readers or searchers, would still be interested in a working solution to copy all files in any directory and its subdirectories containing the an exact `"attribute":"value"` string pair, without having to rely on tools not installed as part of their Operating System.